# Cypress testing element selection using Material UI class na

Tags: material-ui, cypress

I am attempting to write a cypress test that makes sure place cards with stars render before place cards without stars.  To do this I need to first

1. successfully capture the following button element:

```html
<div class="MuiPaper-root MuiPaper-elevation MuiPaper-rounded MuiPaper-elevation8 MuiCard-root css-f1gcjq-MuiPaper-root-MuiCard-root">
<button
  class="MuiButtonBase-root MuiButton-root MuiButton-text MuiButton-textPrimary MuiButton-sizeMedium MuiButton-textSizeMedium Mui-disabled MuiButton-root MuiButton-text MuiButton-textPrimary MuiButton-sizeMedium MuiButton-textSizeMedium css-b0wnbl-MuiButtonBase-root-MuiButton-root"
  tabindex="-1"
  type="button"
  disabled=""
>
  <div class="MuiStack-root css-17gzjms-MuiStack-root">
    <h6
      class="MuiTypography-root MuiTypography-h6 css-17kq1pg-MuiTypography-root"
    >
      Central KY Motorsports
    </h6>
    <div class="MuiBox-root css-0">
      <svg
        class="MuiSvgIcon-root MuiSvgIcon-colorSecondary MuiSvgIcon-fontSizeLarge css-tiotyx-MuiSvgIcon-root"
        focusable="false"
        aria-hidden="true"
        viewBox="0 0 24 24"
        data-testid="StarIcon"
      >
        <path
          d="M12 17.27 18.18 21l-1.64-7.03L22 9.24l-7.19-.61L12 2 9.19 8.63 2 9.24l5.46 4.73L5.82 21z"
        ></path>
      </svg>
    </div>
  </div>
</button>
</div>
```

2. observe wether or not the following (or any) svg element is nested inside of the button:

```html
<svg class="MuiSvgIcon-root MuiSvgIcon-colorSecondary MuiSvgIcon-fontSizeLarge css-tiotyx-MuiSvgIcon-root" 
  focusable="false" 
  aria-hidden="true" 
  viewBox="0 0 24 24" 
  data-testid="StarIcon">
    <path d="M12 17.27 18.18 21l-1.64-7.03L22 9.24l-7.19-.61L12 2 9.19 8.63 2 9.24l5.46 4.73L5.82 21z"></path>
</svg>
```

Once I complete these two tasks, I shouldn't have trouble with the rest of the test.  Does any one know how to capture the button element above for a cy.get().  How about how to check for the presence of an svg tag inside of the button wrapper?

This is my first attempt at a test.  It fails. Cypress doesn't recognize this element. I am trying to figure out what to put inside of cy.get() so that cypress can recognize the button element
:

```js
it('should render place cards with stars before place cards without stars if they exist', () => {
  // Get all place cards and store their elements in an array
  cy.get('.MuiCardContent-root.css-46bh2p-MuiCardContent-root')
    .should('have.length.gt', 1)
    .then(($placeCards) => {
      // Filter place cards with stars
      const starPlaceCards = $placeCards.filter('[data-testid="StarIcon"]')
      // Get the index of the first place card with a star
      const starIndex = $placeCards.index(starPlaceCards);

      if (starPlaceCards.length > 0) {
        // If there are place cards with stars, 
        // check their positions relative to the other place cards
        const noStarIndex = $placeCards.not('[data-testid="StarIcon"]').index();
        expect(starIndex).to.be.lessThan(noStarIndex);
      } else {
        // If there are no place cards with stars, the test passes
        expect(starIndex).to.equal(-1);
      }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm not following everything - for example ***It fails because I cannot capture the MUI tag*** - what's that mean?

This is how I'd approach it

- use `:has([data-testid="StarIcon"])` in `filter` and `not` because that attribute is on a child.
- use `.first().index()` and `.last().index()` to get highest and lowest of each type

```js
cy.get('.MuiCardContent-root')
  .should('have.length.gt', 1)
  .should($placeCards => {

    const starred = $placeCards.filter(':has([data-testid="StarIcon"])')
      .last().index()

    const notStarred = $placeCards.not(':has([data-testid="StarIcon"])')
      .first().index()

    expect(starred).to.be.gt(notStarred)
  })
```

**Code smell**

The `if (starPlaceCards.length > 0)` seems to indicate the page is not set up correctly for this test.

Make sure there are several cards of each type when arranging the test, then it's not necessary the have an `if()` in the code.

Comment: This doesn't work: cy.get('.MuiCardContent-root').  Cypress doesn't recongnize this element.  I am trying to figure out what to put inside of those single quotes so that cypress can recognize the button element.

Comment: That selector is for the card itself - I took off the other class you used because is looks like it has a hash from React styled components, and you know it could change. But your question does not contain the HTML for the card, so please be kind enough to add it and I'll find a working selector for you.

Comment: Plus - you don't need the button - you need the card (you are testing the order of those) and the star svg (which dictates the order).

Comment: Thank you!  The css for the card is: <div class="MuiCardContent-root css-46bh2p-MuiCardContent-root">.  Ive tried cy.get('.MuiCardContent-root css-46bh2p-MuiCardContent-root') and cy.get('.MuiCardContent-root.css-46bh2p-MuiCardContent-root').  Neither work

Comment: By itself the card element doesn't get you very far - it may be possible to tag it with another `data-testid` attribute, or get it using `.parents()` traversal command from the tag you already have (`data-testid="StarIcon"`) since that one is inside the card.

Comment: You should add the whole card HTML to the question instead of just the button (first HTML block).

Comment: Thanks!  Ill try adding a data-testid